# How to add Hangfire as service with custom configuration on asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I wan't to add some configuration to hangfire. It's easy going the documented way but there is one option that depends on User setting so I wan't to do it like this:

```
IGlobalConfiguration hangfireConfiguration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings();

 if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("HangfireUseMemoryStorage"))
 {
    hangfireConfiguration.UseMemoryStorage();
 }
    else
 {
    hangfireConfiguration.UseStorage(new MySqlStorage(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        new MySqlStorageOptions
        {
            TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
        })
    );
};
```

But how to add a service with this configuration? Trying

```
services.AddHangfire(hangfireConfiguration);
```

leads to

```
cannot convert from 'Hangfire.IGlobalConfiguration' to 'System.Action<Hangfire.IGlobalConfiguration>'
```

So how can I add my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define the hangfire configuration, you will need to add it like this,

> [Taken from Hangfire Docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html)

> [Hangfire 1.7 Release Docs](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/hangfire/latest/hangfire.pdf)

```
// Add Hangfire services.
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            DisableGlobalLocks = true
        }));

    // Add the processing server as IHostedService
    services.AddHangfireServer();
```

You can add the if/else on which storage to use based on `Configuration.GetValue<bool>("HangfireUseMemoryStorage")`

Comment: But in this case I would have to duplicate the other settings.

Comment: [Hangfire Documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/hangfire/latest/hangfire.pdf) ... I would suggest checking section 6.1.6 and 6.1.7. *In ASP.NET Core
environments global configuration class is hidden inside the AddHangfire method*